# How would you use Markov chains to find characteristics of English text?

Tags: statistics, cluster-analysis, markov-chains

I am working on a project that involves identifying characteristics of text in specific groups. For example, let's say there are two groups of texts: one containing emails sent to employees and one containing emails sent to bosses. The idea is to explore there are syntactic or word choice differences when writing an email to someone below and above you. My initial method was to use k-means clustering to identify syntax sequences and sequences of words that were (1) unique to each group and (2) identified further sub-groups (which was successful).

However, someone has suggested that I use Markov chains to analyze individuals' email-writing habits and identify individuals' email characteristics of each group (and they say I should arrive at the same sequences). I have never used Markov chains before, and I'm quite lost as I'm trying to figure this out. How would Markov chains lead me to syntactic or word sequences? Is there a tutorial out there for this kind of thing? Any help and guidance in getting me started here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should definitely have a look at [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation).

This method allows capturing distributions of topics in a corpus. The main reference for this paper is [Thomas L. Griffiths and Mark Steyvers (2004)](https://www.pnas.org/content/101/suppl_1/5228). If you want more hands-on materials, I'd suggest you look at this website (https://github.com/sekhansen) which provides nice tutorials on this subject.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at that a bit, and my understanding is that it's very similar to clustering in the sense that clusters are formed based on latent topics?